# Not possible to export EAR file from Eclipse 3.6.2

Tags: java, eclipse, ear

I have written some Java code that I need to export into an EAR file. I am using Eclipse 3.6.2 I have looked at
http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/tjexpear.html
but the problem is that I do not have the export destination "J2EE"--> EAR file in Eclipse.

Also when I go to New--> File --> Other there is not such an option. I did add the JAR-file "ejb-api-3.0.jar" to my project though and Eclipse does not give me any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Eclipse Version are you using? Check in Help>About Eclipse. You should be using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Comment: Hello Abhishek, I am using Eclipse SDK, Version: 3.6.2, 
Build id: M20110210-1200. I assume that is not the right one!? Do I need to download the EE IDE you mentioned? Thank you,Peter; the 2nd one on here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [Eclipse Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr2) for making War Files. You can also add the required plugins into your existing Eclipse but downloading the Java EE version would be much easier.